# Yum fails on first server in mirrorlist

Tags: redhat, yum, package-managers

After installing the EPEL repo via RPM on a 6.1 RHEL box, I have the following yum config

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
```

The box has internet connectivity, and can download the mirrorlist fine, but the first server on the mirror list is currently down, and any yum command gives me:

```
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again
```

Maybe I'm wrong, but shouldn't yum skip to the next mirror in the list in this instance?

Is there a configuration setting missing/incorrect that prevents this from happening? Or is my assumption of how this should be working flawed?

Comment: try removing the `failovermethod=priority` part in the `mirrorlist` line

Comment: yep, tried that - same result

Answer (score 0):

**Remove that **#** sign beside name in the configuration file and check if it works.**

Comment: # signifies a comment in Linux. So you should remove them to make your yum server to be able to get access to this base URL.

Comment: my understanding is that you would specify the baseurl OR the mirrorlist, not both.